# How to get components from rss using php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, rss

I want to know to get components from rss using php.
I have created a php code, when I was running it on wampsever it was running well but when I ran it on my website this error was showing
PHP code is

```
<?php
$feeds = array('http://feeds.feedburner.com/ndtvnews-top-stories?format=xml');
foreach( $feeds as $feed ) {
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($feed);

       foreach($xml->channel->item as $item)
         {
           $date_format = "j-n-Y"; // 7-7-2008

           $link = $item->link;

            echo date($date_format,strtotime($item->pubDate));  
            echo '<a href="'.$item->link.'" target="_blank">'.$item->title.'</a>';
             echo '<div>' . $item->description . '</div>';


         }
    }
?>
```

and Error is

> PHP Error Message
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]:
>   http://feeds.feedburner.com/ndtvnews-top-stories?format=xml:1: parser
>   error : Document is empty in /home/a7989425/public_html/rss.php on
>   line 5
>
> PHP Error Message
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: in
>   /home/a7989425/public_html/rss.php on line 5
>
> Free Web Hosting
>
> PHP Error Message
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in
>   /home/a7989425/public_html/rss.php on line 5
>
> PHP Error Message
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]:
>   http://feeds.feedburner.com/ndtvnews-top-stories?format=xml:1: parser
>   error : Start tag expected, '<' not found in
>   /home/a7989425/public_html/rss.php on line 5
>
> PHP Error Message
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: in
>   /home/a7989425/public_html/rss.php on line 5
>
> PHP Error Message
>
> Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: ^ in
>   /home/a7989425/public_html/rss.php on line 5
>
> PHP Error Message
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/a7989425/public_html/rss.php on line 7

please help 
thanks

Comment: Works for me. Perhaps you don't have the relevant [wrappers](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.http.php) enabled.

Comment: Jon Stirling how to check wrapper is enabled

Comment: I believe it's this [ini directive](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen).